# How can i check Today is Equal to DayName in SharePoint Designer Workflow with out any customCode

Tags: sharepoint-designer, email, date-time

I have a workflow, it will run on weekly basis, i have to check Today is equal to some DayName. then i hav to send an email.

How can i check Today is Equal to DayName, here DayName is String.

Answer (score 0):

There are not many date activities in SharePoint Designer.

There is no activity giving you the name of the day as a string which you could compare against. You will need to code your own activity if you're using SharePoint 2010, for 2013 you will need a custom WebService.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot fetch name but you can get Long Date from your Date variable and using substring operation you may be able to achieve what you want.

[Here's an example](http://nishon.blogspot.in/2013/06/get-day-of-week-in-sharepoint-2010.html)